# How to create a record through, has many association with two foreign keys.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, foreign-keys

I need to create a route which is associated to a location.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :routes,:foreign_key => "origin_id"
end
```

and a route belongs to different locations:

```
class Route < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :origin, :class_name => 'Location', :foreign_key => 'location_id'
 belongs_to :destination, :class_name => 'Location', :foreign_key => 'destination_id'
  validates :origin, :presence => {:message => 'origin cannot be blank'}
end

location.routes.create({
                    :destination    => resort_location,
                    :destination_id => resort_location.id,
                    :total_distance => body['route_summary']['total_distance'],
                    :total_time     => body['route_summary']['total_time'],
                    :raw            => response.body
                   })
```

Records get create without origin and destination, even though I do have the presence validation.
Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Try using the column name instead of the relation, like validates :location_id

Answer (score 0):

Code looks okay to me -

```
location.routes.create({
       :destination    => resort_location, #-> where is resort_location defined?
       :destination_id => resort_location.id,
       :total_distance => body['route_summary']['total_distance'],
       :total_time     => body['route_summary']['total_time'],
       :raw            => response.body
})
```

Your `validates` method also needs to be for a specific attribute (not a relation). In your case, it should be like this:

```
validates :location_id, presence: {message: 'You need an origin!'}
```

Do you have any errors / logs for this?

Comment: :destination    => resort_location this was wrong, only the id is required